# Load html file using iFrame or <object> but restrict direct access from URL

Tags: html, .htaccess

So my application needs to load a file from a folder, that file loads many other files within same folder. Here is the code:

```
<object id="embed_articulate" type="text/html" data="FILE_PATH"></object>
```

This works fine but then I can also access `http://URL/FILE_PATH` and it opens that file also i can open any other file that this file depends on within same directory.

Is there a way to restrict URL access & only load in object?

NOTE: do not tell me why I do this, it was done like this so I have to work around it.

I tried adding htaccess **Deny From All** which worked for URL but it did not load in object either.

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)? [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(xml|swf|html|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|php)$ - [F]
```

If anyone knows that there is something wrong with this please let me know.

Now I can load that html file through iframe but can not access directly from URL gives 403.