# Deny direct URL access but nor iframe src in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I don't know if what i need to do is possible but this the problem...

I have this folder structure:

PDF

-index.php

-SUBFOLDER1

--index.html

-SUBFOLDER2

--index.html
...

Index.php receive a parameter (POST Method) and pass it to an iframe src.

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $_POST['link'];?>"</iframe>
```

so can be

```
<iframe src="http://mydevsite.com/PDF/SUBFOLDER1/"></iframe>
```

My problem is to allow this access from iframe of index.php but deny all direct access of any subfolder from browser navigation bar.
For example, http://mydevsite.com/PDF/SUBFOLDER1/ could not accessible in browser.

I tried in .htaccess at the same level than index.php

```
Options -Indexes
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

But it does not works.

In index.php i can use a php header location instead of iframe if solution is easier with it.

I hope there's a solution to this problem.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Why don't you just include the html into your php, instead of messing around with iframes? `<?php include 'SUBFOLDER1/index.html';?>` You can then block all direct access to those subfolders. I don't know if there is a way to differentiate between being called from a url access or being called from an iframe.

Comment: could you explain more please ?

Comment: Wherever you have `<iframe src="<?php echo $_POST['link'];?>"</iframe>` replace it with `<?php include 'path/to/index.html'; ?>`. php being able to include raw html is one of its fundamental properties, and why it is so friendly towards generating web pages. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

Comment: Using include does not work because asset url in index.html are relatives and so are missing using include from the parent. What it would make work the htaccess using INCLUDE instead of IFRAME ? what about HEADER LOCATION also ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load html file using iFrame or <object> but restrict direct access from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641859/load-html-file-using-iframe-or-object-but-restrict-direct-access-from-url)

Comment: sorry but my main problem is not make it work INCLUDE instead of IFRAME but how deny access from except server...